# How to move a Mercurial repository created on a local PC to a web server?

Tags: mercurial

I have created and committed to Mercurial repository that was created on my local drive. I now have a remote Windows 2003 web server setup to serve repositories via hgwebdir.cgi.

How do I move the locally created repository to the web server?

It looks like an ftp of the .hg folder on the local drive to the remote web server does the trick. Am I doing it the right way. Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copying the `.hg` directory is a completely valid way to do it.

**NOTE:** You will probably want to exclude, remove or edit the `.hg/hgrc` file if you have one, as it may contain an absolute path to the original location of the repository.

You could also initialise an empty repository on the remote server, ensure that write permissions are set up correctly, and then run `hg push https://wherever`.  I haven't measured, but I imagine that this method would be slower.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Probably is slower but then again it is a one of operation so probably less error prone to use the push over ftp.