# Mercurial -- unclear on what is the name of my local repository

Tags: mercurial, repository

From reading [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963040/how-to-clone-repository-to-a-remote-server-repository-with-mercurial), I understand that to clone a local repository to a server, I need to enter the command

```
hg clone yourlocalrepo ssh://you@server//home/you/repo
```

The ssh part I get.  But how do I tell what to enter for yourlocalrepo?  Is this the name of my local repository?  If so how do I tell what that name is?

EDIT: edited to clarify that I want to put the local repo on the server, not vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yourlocalrepo` isn't the name of the source respository - its the location (e.g. directory).  The command is being executed from the parent of the directory with the repository.

BTW: Some 3rd-party hg services don't support a cloning a repo this way to create it on the remote site.  Instead, they require that you create the (empty) repository on the server in advance first.  Then you `hg push` your repository to the empty repository.  The remote repository will sometimes give you a way to copy the remote repository URL to the clipboard for pasting into the `push` command.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a local copy of the repository, you can skip "yourlocalrepo" and mercurial will just clone the server repository into a folder in your current directory, in the case of your example it would create a folder called "repo" in the directory where you ran the command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; my question was poorly written.  I want to do the reverse -- clone my local repo to the server.

Comment: I see, then you might want to take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654341/how-to-move-a-mercurial-repository-created-on-a-local-pc-to-a-web-server